# SAP NetWeaver hot deployment

Tags: jsf-1.2, netweaver

I am working in a project which is based on Java/J2EE (JSF, Icefaces) and SAP NetWeaver combination. Currently, we are building/deploying the application using ant, for every small change in .jspx file or some .html file, we have do re-build.

Just wanted to know, if I can browse the deployment location like other application servers (Jboss,tomcat,weblogic) and manually deploy the respective changed file. Any possibility?

Does it have hot deployment? I am using SAP J2EE engine/7.00.

Any ideas or approach to make it quickly deploy.

Answer (score 1):

You can update JSPs, html, and those type of resources by copying them directly into the web app's working directory.  Mine, for example, is /usr/sap/(sid)/J00/j2ee/cluster/apps/(vendor)/(appname)/servlet_jsp/(webapp_root)/root/(your jsps are here).

Note, however, that you will lose those changes if you restart the app server instance because it will reload your application from the database.

Comment: I forgot to add that you can replace jars the same way but you will have to restart the app via mmc or nwa. Again, don't restart the app server or your app will be reset to its original deployment.

Comment: @tdury: I can browse the deployment location: but when I edit a jsp and refresh the same jsp the browser to check my change, its not reflecting. I haven't restarted application server as you said.

Comment: Search for the generated java and class file. If they were generated you need to delete them to force NW to regenerate them.

Comment: srk: I recently had to go through this on a new installation, so let me amend my answer: you need to use config tool to open the servlet_jsp service on the instance and set the "productive" parameter to false.  Then, all you have to do is copy the new JSP into the application's cluster/apps/<your app>/servlet_jsp/<context>/root/<package> directory and overwrite the old JSP there.  There's no need to delete the generated java/class file in the work directory.