# How to catch runtime exceptions in jspx pages

Tags: jsf, icefaces, jsf-1.2, jspx

This is in continuation with my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408444/sap-netweaver-hot-deployment/21488930?noredirect=1#comment32462581_21488930). I couldn't find solution for that. Hence I am trying to debug my application view layer jspx.

I realized that jspx is quite different from jsp, like it doesn't allow scriptlets. I know, that usage of this(scriptlets) is not at all recommended.

I have a particular SAP Net weaver server where hot deployment of jspx/jsp/html is not working.  I have checked other alternatives like remote debugging, break points in jspx. But, its SAP net weaver, have some configuration issues. I have one option atleast to put sysouts, to trace runtime exceptions. But as its jspx files sysouts in scriptlets are not working. If it was jsp instead of jspx there, I could have traced/debugged the issues quickly using scriptlets temporarily until the issue got resolved atleast by using Sysouts.

Is there any equivalent code to this scriptlet(used in jsp)which we use very rarely.

```
<% System.out.println("The line above the null pointer exception : "+object.getPropery());%
```

Any equivalent code in jspx or icefaces components.

How do we debug a jspx page or handle exceptions inside a jspx page and find out errors.
Any eclipse plugins or tools available?

Comment: Your question is very strange. Are you implying that exceptions are being completely swallowed and thus you're tempted/forced to add scriptlets for poor man's logging purposes? Why don't you concentrate on fixing the actual problem that exceptions are being completely swallowed? That should namely not happen.